# What is the meaning of the lyrics-liner 'a quarter tank and almost gone' meaning?

Tags: lyrics

[Source at 1:41](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CdEfL-XrSk)

This seems not to be a sentence.How should we interpret it?

Edit: Just another example
[Source at 1:08](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h0Arg_-380)

> Ther's such a difference between us and a million miles.

*And* seems to be acting like *which is*.Does not it?

Comment: It's not meant to be a sentence  It's an adverbial phrase. *Quarter tank* refers to the amount or level of gasoline/petrol in a motor vehicle's *gas tank* (American English); it can also refer to the amount of food in a person's stomach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it as a metaphor for a vanishing love, exhausting the fuel of passion. Put some verses together:

1. "You brought the fire to a world so cold": beginning of the story, the tank is full of passion, enough to set the world on fire.
2. "With half the tank and empty heart": after a while, half of the fuel is burnt, the relationship is going out, see the play on "half-empty tank" and "empty heart"
3. "A quarter tank is almost gone": the end is approaching
4. "We're out of time on the highway to never": the end of the road

A form of poetry.

Comment: 'And' acts like 'which is'.

Comment: I am not fully sure. In some contexts I understand it as "but". No more love, but something remains